# Can the first argument to setpgid() be a session leader or a group leader?

Tags: c, linux, process

From The Linux Programming Interface

> ```
> #include <unistd.h>
> int setpgid(pid_t  pid , pid_t  pgid );
> ```
>
> The pid argument may not specify a process that is a session leader. Violation
>   of this rule results in the error  EPERM .

1. Why can't `pid` be a session leader?
2. Can `pid` be a group leader and why?

   If yes, after the call to `setpgid()`, in which group will the other processes originally in the group
   originally led by  process `pid` be:

   - the original group whose gid is `pid` which now has lost process `pid` and has no group leader, or
   - the new group `pgid` which process `pid` is changed to?

   I suspect the first might contradict to what the book described for `setsid()`:

   > The restriction against a process group leader being able to call setsid() is necessary because, without it, the process group leader would be able to place itself in another (new) session, while other members of the process group remained in the original session. (**A new process group would not be created, since, by definition, the process group leader’s process group ID is already the same as its process ID.**) This  would  violate  the  strict  two-level  hierarchy  of  sessions  and  process  groups, whereby all members of a process group must be part of the same session.

Thanks.

Some related questions [Can a leader of a process session or group leave for another existing session or group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50592958/can-a-leader-of-a-process-session-or-group-leave-for-another-existing-session-or)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is specified by POSIX (which means it applies to everything calling itself "Unix", not just Linux).  http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setpgid.html says:

> ```
> ERRORS
>     [EPERM] The process indicated by the pid argument is a session leader.
> ```

The spec doesn't say why this rule exists, but I believe the rationale stated by dbush is correct: a *session* leader must always be a process group leader; if it could move into another process group, it would cease to be a process group leader, violating the invariant.

However, a process that is only a process group leader, not a session leader, *may* put itself into another process group (ceasing to be a process group leader) and may then take itself back out of the process group and become a process group leader again.  Job control shells actually *have* to do this under some circumstances: note the bit at the bottom of the RATIONALE section of the spec

> One non-obvious use of setpgid() is to allow a job control shell to return itself to its original process group (the one in effect when the job control shell was executed). A job control shell does this before returning control back to its parent when it is terminating or suspending itself as a way of restoring its job control "state" back to what its parent would expect.

POSIX doesn't explain why the job control shell would have changed its process group in the first place, but the [GNU C Library manual section on implementing job control](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Initializing-the-Shell.html) fills in the gap:

> When a shell program that normally performs job control is started, it has to be careful in case it has been invoked from another shell that is already doing its own job control.
>
> A subshell that runs interactively has to ensure that it has been placed in the foreground by its parent shell before it can enable job control itself.
>
> [...]
>
> Once the subshell has been placed into the foreground by its parent shell, it can enable its own job control. It does this by calling `setpgid` to put itself into its own process group, and then calling `tcsetpgrp` to place this process group into the foreground.

And then, of course, it has to undo that again if the subshell is suspended (e.g. Bash has a `suspend` builtin that does this).

Also notice that a job control shell does *not* establish itself as a *session* leader, even if it's not a subshell of anything.  The session is initialized by whatever program is responsible for setting up the controlling terminal; that program is typically the parent and pre-`exec` identity of the outermost shell running in the terminal.  For instance, [`xterm` calls `setsid`](https://github.com/joejulian/xterm/blob/defc6dd5684a12dc8e56cb6973ef973e7a32caa3/main.c#L3588) after opening a pseudoterminal and forking, but before `exec`-ing the program that will run in that terminal window.

Comment: Sessions, jobs, and process groups have had a complex evolution in Unix. I still remember when it was possible to login and start seeing output from someone else who had gotten disconnected. :)

Comment: @Barmar Yeah, this was all still in flux as recently as 4.3BSD, if I remember correctly.  And the glibc manual still has a warning in it that job control is optional! (It appears to have been mandatory since the 2001 revision of POSIX.)

Comment: Thanks. "a process that is only a process group leader, not a session leader, may put itself into another process group (ceasing to be a process group leader)". In which group are the other processes in the original group of the original group leader,  the original group whose gid is the pid of the original group leader, or the new group of the original group leader? See my update to my post

Comment: @Tim I _think_ the answer is "setpgid affects only one process, any other processes in the group it left remain in that group; nothing cares whether the pgid of a process group is actually the pid of a process in that group, and nothing much cares whether a process group has a leader" but it doesn't actually come out and _say_ that in the setpgid() spec, and I don't have enough brain right now to parse the entire job control spec and figure out whether that's right.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31916561/must-a-process-group-have-a-running-leader-process appears to be relevant.

Comment: Thanks. In "a process that is only a process group leader, not a session leader, may put itself into another process group (ceasing to be a process group leader)", does this happen only when the process leader creates a new group and leads it, or can this happen also when switching the group leader to another existing group? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50592958/can-a-leader-of-a-process-session-or-group-leave-for-another-existing-session-or

Answer (score 2):

A session leader is always a process group leader.  If you were to move it to another process group, it would no longer be the process group leader, which violates the preceding rule.

Comment: Thanks. Can pid be a group leader and why?